# GDB examine command, multiple units at target address

Tags: gdb

I am studying the book "Hacking The Art of Exploitation 2nd Edition" on my own and have reached the first set of obstacles.

In GDB I can understand that this code:

```
x/x $rip
```

Will examine the register $rip and output in hexadecimal.

But what does this code do:

```
x/2x $rip
```

The book says it is examining multiple units at the target address. But does that mean it is showing the value of $rip the next 2 times it changes. Or does it mean something else?

One more question as Columbo would say. After I invoke the examine command, I get:

```
0x100000f00 <main+8> 0x00fc45c7
```

What does main+8 mean?

Answer (score 5):

> `x/x $rip` Will examine the register $rip and output in hexadecimal.

That's incorrect: it will examine *memory* pointed to by `$rip`. If you wanted to examine `$rip` itself, you'd use `print/x $rip`.

> But what does this code do: `x/2x $rip`

It examines two words of memory, pointed to by `$rip`.

> What does `main+8` mean

It means that you are looking at memory containing instructions, at offset `8` from the start of `main()`

Comment: Thank you. The only understanding I have of $rip is that it points to the current instruction that the processor is reading. When you say it examines two words of memory pointed to by $rip, does that mean it is looking at the current instruction and then the one afer that? What if I put x/100x $rip? Does that look at the next 100 instructions?

Comment: @jimbo123 "does that mean it is looking at the current instruction and then the one afer that?" -- that would be true if each instruction took one word, which is true on many RISC processors, but not on x86. No: you are looking at 2 32-bit words, and that can cover as many as 8 instructions (shortest x86 instruction is just 1 byte), or as few as one (longest x86 instruction is 15 bytes).

Comment: Thanks so much! This is maybe a very basic question but it helps me understand the other parts of the book